# MySql 5.6 Windows reset root password for the service

Tags: windows, mysql-5.6

I did all this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

The mysqld is running in the command prompt and I can connect with the new password. But, the database is gone.

Luckily i found my root password again, and tried to login (with workbench) when the service is running normally with the "networkservice" user. Now I wonder why I can't change the password for the networkservice instance. It seems that the database is hooked up to that windows user.

I installed the mysql with the installation wizard.I have tried a lot of things, I cant reset the password for the MySQL 5.6 service running on Windows 8. I have tried running the reset as administrator in cmd, and it starts an instance in the command prompt, I can connect with the new password, but it's not the same as the MySql56 service...

I have tried to run start paramters in the service options, but it seems that windows are ignoring it when starting the services.

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the defaults-file destination to the hidden folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html